# Best way to return a vector member variable to external class

Tags: c++, vector, reference, smart-pointers

I'm trying to write an LED strip driver in c++.  Right now I have a `Strip` class and a `Driver` class; the `Strip` class abstracts an LED strip with several pixels, while the `Driver` class aggregates the `Strip` data into a single buffer to send over a UDP connection.

The relevant partial classes:

```
class Strip {
  public:
    ...
    ??? getPixelData();
    int getPixelDataLength();
  protected:
    std::vector<unsigned char> mPixelData;

class Driver {
  public:
    ...
    void aggregateStrips();
  protected:
    vector<unsigned char> mBuffer;
```

`serialize` writes all of the red-green-blue pixel data to a `vector<unsigned char>`.  Then the driver calls `Strip.getPixelData()` to get the address to `mPixelData`, and `getPixelDataLength()` to figure out how many bytes to `memcpy()`.

`aggregateStrips()` does something like this:

```
int packetLength = 0;
for(auto strip : Strips) {
    memcpy(&mBuffer[packetLength], strip->getPixelData(), strip->getPixelDataLength());
    packetLength += strip.getPixelDataLength();
}
```

My question is -- what should `getPixelData()` return?  Should it return a smart pointer (`shared_ptr`?) to the vector?  Or perhaps a reference?  I only really want the address (and length), because I plan to `memcpy` it.

thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Typically you would return a const reference to the vector (`std::vector<unsigned char> const &`), and in this case you should also make the method const since it doesn't modify the object:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> const & getPixelData() const;
```

The caller can decide if they need to make a copy.

```
// Causes copy-initialization.
std::vector<unsigned char> copy = a_strip.getPixelData();

// Binds a new reference to the existing vector; no copy is made.
std::vector<unsigned char> const & not_a_copy = a_strip.getPixelData();
```

---

`getPixelDataLength()` could also probably be made a const member of the class. Try to make any members that don't change the object const members as it will allow them to be called on `Strip` objects that are const.

Comment: To implement `getPixelData()`, do I just `return mBuffer`? Or `return &mBuffer`?

Comment: @nathanlachenmyer `return mBuffer;`. `&` would take the address, which you only want when you need a pointer. (References are not pointers.)

Comment: If you want to use the return value in a memcpy (bad idea mixing c style copying with C++ objects) then you will have to do this. const char* getPixelData(void) { return mPixelData.data(); } However I prefer cdhowie's suggestion on how the interface should look like.

Comment: @rakeshdn You wouldn't need that interface at all, you could simply do `foo.getPixelData().data()` at the call site to obtain such a pointer.

Comment: +1 For advocating for `const` correctness. More discussion about this can be found in the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#con2-by-default-make-member-functions-const).

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector` exposes the buffer it manages via its `data()` method, which in this case would return `unsigned char*` or `const unsigned char *` depending on whether or not `Strip`/`mBuffer` is `const`. This method was added in C++11.

As a side note, it's good design to make your read-only methods as `const` (after the parenthesized method parameters) so they can be called on `const` instances of their class and aren't allowed to modify any member variables.

I would define `getPixelData()` as:

```
const unsigned char* getPixelData() const
{
  return mBuffer.data();
}
```

Similarly, I'd write `getPixelDataLength()` as:

```
std::size_t getPixelDataLength() const
{
  return mBuffer.size();
}
```

As another side note, `for(auto strip : Strips)` actually copies each strip. Your program would be more efficient if you referenced each existing strip without copying it:

```
for (const auto& strip : Strips) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks!  I didn't actually know I could use references with auto -- that's really clever.  I also really appreciate you walking me through how you'd approach this.

Comment: No problem. Actually, the C++ standards committee is currently considering making `for` loops even simpler by allowing something like `for (strip : strips)` without even having to specify `auto&`!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning the vector I would return a pair of (const) iterators to the start and end of the vector:

```
using PixelIterator = std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator;
class Strip {
 ... 
 PixelIterator begin() const {
   return mPixelData.begin();
 }
 PixelIterator end() const {
   return mPixelData.end();
 }
};
```

I would avoid using `memcopy` in c++ if you can. With the iterators you can easily append to your buffer vector:

```
for(const auto& strip : strips)
  mBuffer.insert(mBuffer.end(). strip.begin(),  strip.end());
```

As was already pointed out, use `auto&` in a range-based loop to avoid a copy.

You shouldn't need to maintain separate length variables as you can easily get the size of `std::vector`.